# Stored Procedure Continue Handler Error

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am not getting where i am having error in my syntax, The MySql says that unknown system veriable done : delimiter |

```
CREATE PROCEDURE UPDATELOMON ()    
BEGIN 

  DECLARE First_cur CURSOR FOR SELECT oraginal_level,level FROM LOMTEMP;
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done := TRUE;

  OPEN First_cur;

  FirstLoop: LOOP
  FETCH First_cur INTO oraginal,toupdate;
  IF done THEN
  LEAVE FirstLoop;
  END IF;

  CALL updt(oraginal,toupdate);
  END LOOP FirstLoop;

  CLOSE First_cur;

END;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the delimiter when you create STORED PROCEDURE:

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS UPDATELOMON$$
CREATE PROCEDURE UPDATELOMON ()    
BEGIN 

  DECLARE First_cur CURSOR FOR SELECT oraginal_level,level FROM LOMTEMP;
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done := TRUE;

  OPEN First_cur;

  FirstLoop: LOOP
  FETCH First_cur INTO oraginal,toupdate;
  IF done THEN
  LEAVE FirstLoop;
  END IF;

  CALL updt(oraginal,toupdate);
  END LOOP FirstLoop;

  CLOSE First_cur;

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

By default, MySQL itself recognizes the semicolon as a statement delimiter, so you must redefine the delimiter temporarily to cause MySQL to pass the entire stored program definition to the server. Otherwise, MySQL breaks CREATE PROCEDURE, before it reaches the END statement (on the first semicolon, which, in your case, is before CONTINUE HANDLER statement).

You can see the documentation for more details: 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/stored-programs-defining.html

Comment: Great, now you can accept the answer :) Here's an explanation how  to do that, and why - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

On @Zagor23's answer. You can remove `$$` at `DROP PROCEDURE...` line and put `DELIMITER $$` after it. So you will have the following:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS UPDATELOMON;
DELIMITER $$
```